# How to analyze the Response time distribution graph in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have executed a load test on a web application. I have got the results and while creating the document regarding the test results, I started to analyze the response time distribution graph. But I couldn't really understand how to calculate the total response time of a specific request.

I'm attaching the graph photo.[image]

Can anyone describe how much is the total response time for the displayed sampler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For load tests, the total response time of a given page or request is meaningless. It makes more sense to look at the **mode** response time, vs the **median** response time vs the **average** response time.

In your graph, the mode response time is 37800 ms (5 responses took this length of time).

The median response time (the one that is halfway through the list) is 37700 ms. (there were 27 responses, so response #14 is the median).

The average response time is the sum of all response times divided by the number of responses.

These numbers tell you that a typical response to this call takes over 35 seconds, which is a rather poor response.

The total time taken isn't relevant beside that: total time really only matters in the context of an end-to-end cycle (that is, it takes a certain amount of time to perform function X).

Answer (score 1):

As a performance test, you will probably want to communicate to the team that most users experience page load times of 37200 and 38300, using the mathematical functions such as discussed previously by [Kate Paulk](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/users/422/kate-paulk).

Finding out what the conditions were when users who had a faster response will help the team decide how to give everyone this faster experience. The response times around 28400 are statistically called [Outliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier).

You might want to run the test again with server monitoring, but also capture details about the volume of transactions being sent by Jmeter to determine if the source of the slowness for everyone else.